# QML widget not updated when signal is emitted

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have a widget on in my `screen.qml` file not being updated when I'm emitting a signal. For context I want to fire a signal to disable some of the UI because after clicking certain button, the program has to do heavy stuff in the background and I want to prevent the user from clicking multiple times. Here's is a minimal code, in the qml `dbg_processing` is not being updated (it should take +- 3s of the calculation to end).

**ScreenManager.hpp**

```
class ScreenManager : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(bool processingChangeState READ getProcessingChangeState NOTIFY processingChangeStateChanged);

public:
    ScreenManager();
public slots:
    void doStuff();
signals:
    void processingChangeStateChanged();
private:
    bool processingChangeState = false;
    bool getProcessingChangeState();
```

**ScreenManager.cpp**

```
void ScreenManager::doStuff()
{
    if (!processingChangeState)
    {
        processingChangeState = true;
        emit processingChangeStateChanged();
        //do heavy stuff here
        processingChangeState = false;
        emit processingChangeStateChanged();
    }
}
bool ScreenManager::getProcessingChangeState()
{
    return this->processingChangeState;
}
```

And my QML file looks like this

**screen.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12
import ScreenManager 1.0

Background {
ScreenManager{
        id: screenManager
}
   Text {
      id: dbg_processing
      text: screenManager.processingChangeState
   }
}
   Image {
      id: start_button
      source : "Start.png"
         MouseArea {
            onReleased:screenManager.doStuff()
         }
   }
```

Comment: try to run your heavy task in a separated thread.

Comment: @folibis Yeah it's seems to be that problem, when I removed the heavy task and removed the `processingChangeState = false;` after I can see the value changing. I thought that because a signal was emitted another thread would take care of it.

Comment: Thanks @folibis for the quick answer, everything is working fine now. Cheers.